# Why is my python function to change data type of series object not working?

Tags: python, pandas, function

The function takes a dataframe.
Pretty simple I expect the code below to change the data type of float column to int (works) 
and to "category" if the unique values are less than 2% of the size of the Series object (does not work)

I have a dataframe df with a column "Position" that only has 4 unique values so this column should be "category" data type but is "Object".

So I do memoryHandler(df), but after the column still has "object" as data type, why?

```
def memoryHandler(frame):
    for column in frame:
        if frame[column].dtype == float:
            frame[column] = frame[column].astype("int")        
        if frame[column].nunique() < 0.02*frame[column].size:
            frame[column] = frame[column].astype("category")
```

Comment: Added pandas tag. Please edit if that isn't what you're using here.

Comment: maybe the unique count is never less than 2% of the size

Comment: Thanks for answer. The unique count is less than 2% in the dataframe. The column "Position" has 4 unique values of 497 so that is 4/497 = 1% about..If i check df["Position"].nunique() < 0.02*df["Position"].size the result is 4 < 9,94 so should work?

Comment: There's no such thing as "category" `dtype`.

Comment: this works df["Position"].astype("category"), so there should be a dtype "category"? but does not work with this memoryHandler(df) and question is why

Comment: I suggest you create a full [mcve] that we can run from start to finish to reproduce your issue. Otherwise you're just assuring us that there is no problem with your input, when almost certainly there's something going wrong. It's not difficult to create sample data, for instance, `df = pd.DataFrame({'Position' : np.random.choice(['a', 'b'], 10000)})` gives me a DataFrame where `'Position'` should be converted to category, which seems to work for me with your above code...